# Change Div Order With Jquery/Javascript (not in DOM)

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i'm familiar with the insertAfter() & insertBefore() commands but as we know from the Javascript docs:

> The elements must already be inserted into the document (you can't
>   insert an element after another if it's not in the page).

So I have some code that hides a div in desktop view but displays in mobile, but when it appears I need this div to appear above some other divs, the problem is that at the same time i'm using jquery to insert some other divs so the insertBefore() command isn't working for me, is there a way to do this with items not in the page yet?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("div.tools").addClass("hide-desktop");
$("div.tools").addClass("hide-tablet");
$("#header").addClass("hide-desktop");
$("#header").addClass("hide-tablet");
$("div.mobile-menu").insertBefore("#new-logos");
$("body").prepend($('<div id="new-logo"  class="hide-mobile">'+
    '<div class="header-inner">'+
      '<div class="logo">'+
        '<h1><a href="logo"></a></h1>'+
 ' </div>'
));
</script>

<div class="main-content">
<div id="new-logos" class="hide-mobile">...</div>
<div class="tools hide-desktop hide-tablet"></div>
<div id="header" class="header hide-desktop hide-tablet"></div>
<div class="mobile-menu hide">
<ul class="links">
<li>
<a href="#">Log In</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Help</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add your HTML with this...

Comment: write this `$("div.mobile-menu").insertBefore("#new-logos")` last in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine from what you're implying, more details?

http://jsfiddle.net/Pa32R/

```
$('<div class="div4">4</div>').appendTo('body');
$('<div class="div5">5</div>').appendTo('body');

$('.div1').insertAfter('.div4');
```